# How to get parallel execution identifier in Maven test run output

Tags: java, maven, logging, maven-3

When using e.g. `mvn test -Tn` to run Maven builds parallelized *n*-fold, how can I get Maven to prefix its log output with the identifier of the parallel test runner? Currently the log output looks like:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
```

which makes it very difficult to tell which instance logged what

I would like it to show some kind of parallel execution (thread, process, whatever) identifier in the logs, like:

```
[1][INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[1][INFO]  T E S T S
[2][INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[2][INFO]  T E S T S
[2][INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[1][INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
```

It's easy enough to get thread identifiers in the log output by adding `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=true` to `MAVEN_OPTS` envionment variable (as described at https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html) but this doesn't seem to affect surefire output, for example:

```
[BuilderThread 1] [INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\redacted\path\to\module2\target\surefire-reports
[BuilderThread 0] [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[BuilderThread 0] [INFO]
[BuilderThread 0] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ module1 ---
[BuilderThread 0] [INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\redacted\path\to\module1\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you! replacing `mvn` with `MAVEN_OPTS=-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=true mvn` produced the thread identifiers in the logs

Answer (score 3):

First by using `-T ...` you don't run the integration tests in parallel you run the building of the modules in parallel.

Furthermore if you are using maven-surefire-plugin you are doing something wrong, cause [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) is for running unit tests whereas [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) is for integration test.

To parallelize the tests itself you should check the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) how to do that.

Apart from that you should use `mvn ... verfiy` to be sure that the `pre-integration-test`, `integration-test` and `post-integration-test` phase have run. If you call `mvn .. integration-test` the `post-integration-test` will not being executed.

Furthermore by definition integration tests can't be parallized cause they usually use resources, are coupled in other ways..only unit tests can be parallized by definition cause they are independent etc.

Comment: Hmm, true, -T indeed parallelizes thing at a higher level. I'll rephrase the question in those terms.

The other notes seem to be accurate, except `mvn integration-test` certainly appears to run `pre-integration-test` phase. I would expect it to not run `post-integration-test`, but this has no bearing on the actual issue in question.

As to whether integration tests can be parallelized or not, that surely depends on how they have been written. I would expect non-parallelizable integration tests to be annotated so.